# How to get Eloquent collection if collection has data or count is > 0?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Consider this example... which gets the image of product.

This function should only get the data if it exists otherwise it should return null... because it will get the images for a product otherwise the site will display a 404 not found image...

// Product.php

```
public function getFileImageURL()
{
    $referType = 1; //Product = 1

    if(File::where('file_refer_id','=', $this->id)
            ->where('file_refer_type','=', $referType)
            ->count()>0)
    {
        return $imageFileItems = File::where('file_refer_id','=', $this->id)
            ->where('file_refer_type','=', $referType)
            ->get();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Additional details

//ProductController.php

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->findProductBySlug($slug);
    $productImages = $product->getFileImageURL();

    return view('pages.product.show', compact('product', 'productImages'));
}
```

// product/show.blade.php

```
@if($productImages)
    <a href=" {{ $productImages->first()->file_url }}" data-lightbox="product-images" data-alt="{{ $productImages->first()->title }}" data-title="{{ $productImages->first()->name }}"><img src="{{ $productImages->first()->file_url }}"></a>
@else
    <a href="#"><img alt="Image not found" src="{{ asset('images/products/404.png') }}"></a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `get()` from Eloquent will always return to you an Eloquent collection; which means you can use collection methods on it.

Considering what you are wanting to do, the following should do the trick:

```
public function getFileImageURL()
{
    $referType = 1; //Product = 1

    $imageFileItems = File::where('file_refer_id','=', $this->id)
            ->where('file_refer_type','=', $referType)
            ->get();

    return $imageFileItems->isNotEmpty() 
        ? $imageFileItems
        : null;
}
```

This also saves you from having to perform an extra, unneccssary, query to get the count of records.

Comment: Considering the revised question... would you do the.. if image, not found any better?

Comment: Based on your additional details, I’d probably alter the method you call to return an image URL for the image or return the 404 URL. That way you can just call the one method and always get back a URL and the logic for which image to display is tucked away nicely.

Comment: How would you alter it?

Comment: Return the 404 URL or the assert URL?

Comment: But then when you access it using first() it returns an error?

Comment: If you’ve got another question or problem about a new implementation, post a new question with all the new details and we can help.